# WPF form application doesn't have the same properties as in the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm learning how to create wpf controls (and windows) with Visual Studio 2019. As a first step, I've tried to generate a Window with a label inside. Using the following code, it looks like this (designer window)

[image: Designer]

```
<Window x:Name="Ventana" x:Class="PhanUtils.Sistema.Recursos.Ventanas.Mensaje"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhanUtils.Sistema.Recursos.Ventanas" 
    Width="580" Height="175" MinWidth="580" MinHeight="175" MaxWidth="580" MaxHeight="175"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="L_Informacion" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="554" Height="126" BorderBrush="#FFCF1E1E" BorderThickness="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, when I run the application and I show the same dialog, it looks like this:

[image: Application]

Does anybody know why I'm having this issue?

Comment: The XAML designer doesn't necessarily calculate the correct size of the window. You should not set the size of the Window and that of the Label at the same time. Just set the Label's Margin, and remove the Width and Height assignments. Then also set the alignments to Stretch (or don't set them at all).

Comment: Alternatively, only set the Label Width and Height, and set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the Window.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! Setting the alignments as Stretch fix my issue

Comment: Or don't set them at all. Stretch is the default.